# Missing prerequisites in Visual Studio 2012 for sharepoint 2013 development

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, installation, sharepoint-2013

I am following the Microsoft tutorial for creating my first sharepoint 2013 app.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142379.aspx )

I have installed on a windows 2008 R2 Server Sharepoint 2013 RTM, done all the farm config stuff RTM, and installed all of Visual Studio 2012 ultimate and update 1 and restarted the server.

I have also followed the instructions for "How to: Set up an on-premises development environment for apps for SharePoint" which is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923.aspx (I have to do this as our dev environment has no internet access)

I have got to the point where running Visual Studio as an Administrator I have named it and chosen "sharepoint-hosted" and validated the server and clicked finish (Step 5).

Instead of getting the next step where I open the AppManifest.xml file I get a message saying "**An error occurred whilst trying to load some required components, Please ensure the following prerequisite components are installed. Microsoft Web Developer Tools and Microsoft Exchange Web Services**"

I have checked VS setup and web developer tools is definetely installed (the only option I have would be to remove it)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know Im a noob here (this is my first post) but I have googled this and searched stack exchange and found nothing that helps me.

Comment: Just making sure: You did install the SharePoint developer tools? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2012/08/16/installing-office-2013-and-sharepoint-2013-developer-tools-preview-for-visual-studio-2012-rtm.aspx

Comment: I believe so, as I don't think you get the option in Visual Studio for the project "Sharepoint 2013 App" unless they are installed, but as I have to use an offline install (as my Dev has no internet access, I could have a mismatch, but I have no idea how to determine if thats the case!) What I downloaded was "Preview 2" if that helps

Comment: This is what Visual Studio is showing as Installed Products

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 11.0.51106.01 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Architecture and Modeling Tools
LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012
Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 - Preview - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012
Office Developer Tools
Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012
Visual Basic 2012
Visual C# 2012
Visual C++ 2012
Visual F# 2012
Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker
NuGet Package Manager
PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer
SQL Server Data Tools
Web Developer Tools
Most products have version 04940-004-0038003-02173

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it after a few trial and errors

With an offline install you have to download the Exchange Web Services component. I had downloaded "EwsManageApi" and installed that.

As the error message specifically refers to Exchange Web services, I looked at other versions and tried the older 1.1 and the 32 bit version, but they didn't work either, ** until ** I relised in my haste that I installed using the default settings (which is for the current user) and not for all users of the machine.

So installing EwsManagedApi32 for all users on a 64 bit server does the trick (for me)

Answer (score 1):

I tried reinstalling the EWS Managed API for All Users, but that didn't solve it for me. In the end the solution was simple:

Just uninstall **BOTH** the EWS Managed API and the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012. After that reinstall **ONLY** the Office Developer Tools. This time the Web Platform Installer will ensure the correct EWS Managed API is also installed.

I also wrote a small blog about this problem:
https://leonzandman.com/2013/02/07/prerequisite-components-error-when-creating-a-visual-studio-2012-sharepoint-2013-app-project/

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the year of 2014:

Install Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.1 (the latest version I can find at this time).